# Is there a way to access default values in an annotation statically?

Tags: java, static, annotations

Suppose you have some annotation `Annot`:

```
@Retention(/*your retention policy*/)
@Target(/*targeted element type*/)
public @interface Annot {
    String value() default "Hello World!";
}
```

And in some related code, say, an annotation processor, you need the default value of the `value()` Annotation field **without** having access to a class that is annotated with `@Annot`. Of course you could simply do

```
public static final String ANNOT_VALUE_DEFAULT = "Hello World!";
```

in your processor class, then change the following in `@Annot`:

```
String value() default Processor.ANNOT_VALUE_DEFAULT;
```

(`Processor` being the class name of your annotation processor). While this works fine with `String`s, the change in `@Annot` fails when your `value()` type is an `enum`. It might fail for other values, too, but `enum` is part of my use case, therefore if this doesn't work, it doesn't matter if other types will work.

Now, of course, the simplest way to resolve this is to simply have the default value specified in `@Annot` **and** `Processor`, separately. But every programmer knows that duplicated constants are not a good idea in general. You might want to automatically reflect changes in one part (e.g. `@Annot`) in the other parts (e.g. `Processor`). For this to work, you'd have to be able to do this:

```
var defaultVal = Annot.value(); // statically (without an instance annotated with @Annot) access default value
```

So, is this static access in any way possible?

### Partial solution

It is not urgent for me to find a solution right now as I already found a semi-convenient workaround (see my answer). Still, because the workaround is a bit "hacky", I want to know if there is a more elegant way to do this.

Comment: Useless side comment: you can also make `DefaultAnnotValues` private static where it's needed (or even a method-local class)

Comment: It seems like you have an answer to your own question. Please split that off into its own answer, you don't want it as part of the question.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis It is not the answer to my question. Rather my question is whether there is another, more elegant way to solve this problem than my given workaround

Comment: _but you, the reader, really need a solution, take a look at this workaround_ **really** sounds like an answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Workaround

If it turns out that there is no satisfying solution to this, but you, the reader, really need a solution, take a look at this workaround:

So, the problem is that you want to access the default value **without** being supplied with a class that is annotated with `@Annot`. Well, who says that you don't have access to such a class? Just add this (preferably package-private) class to your source code:

```
@Annot
class DefaultAnnotValues {
    private static final Annot ANNOT = DefaultAnnotValue.class.getAnnotation(Annot.class);

    static SomeEnum value = ANNOT.value();

    // add all other enum fields with default values here

    private DefaultAnnotValues() {
    }
}
```

Now you can access all default values of your annotation, and when you change a default value in the annotation definition, it will be automatically reflected to wherever you use those defaults.